# BEP20 token not showing any supply and details on bscscan

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, bep20, bscscan

I have just cloned a bep20 token and deployed on bsc test net but after successfull deploy tokens are not allocated to the admin wallet even when I add token to metamask it shows 0 value of token even though I have deployed with same wallet also when I'm checking contract on bsctestscan it shows something like this

[image]

I'm not sure how I can fix this issue if anyone knows please help me fix this issue

Thanks

Comment: What is the address of the token and in which network do I deploy it?

Comment: contract add:   0xAE91c3a83fe9B4bE2423a98260C66436070244a9
I'm deploying on BSC

Comment: do you have the address of the original contract?

Comment: 0xAE91c3a83fe9B4bE2423a98260C66436070244a9

Comment: Please check Above I sent Contract Address